# Using the same jButton in Java to Insert and Update data into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I am building my first Java application. I created separate buttons called SAVE and UPDATE to insert new data into the MySQL database and update modifications respectively. Both buttons are working perfectly, but I am now thinking of combining both functions into one button. How do I go about it?

Below are my codes for the separate buttons that are working perfectly but independently;

SAVE FUNCTION

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

try{

String sql ="Insert into attendance (counseleeID,attendanceDate,present) values (?,?,?)";

                 pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                 pst.setString(1, comboBoxCounseleeID.getSelectedItem().toString());
                 pst.setString(2, ((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                 pst.setString(3, comboBoxPresent.getSelectedItem().toString());
                 pst.execute();


                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");

                 comboBoxCounseleeID.setSelectedItem(null);
                 ((JTextComponent) dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).setText(null); //review  
                 comboBoxPresent.setSelectedItem(null);


                    }        

                   catch(Exception e)
            {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

            }

             finally {
                    try{
                      rs.close();
                          pst.close();
                        // conn.close();
                      }
                      catch(Exception e) {
                                       }
                          } 
                Update_table();
        }
```

UPDATE FUNCTION

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

int p =JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to save these changes?","Update
     Warning",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(p==0){
            try {
                 String s1= comboBoxCounseleeID.getSelectedItem().toString();
                 String s2= ((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
                 String s3= comboBoxPresent.getSelectedItem().toString();

String sql ="UPDATE attendance SET counseleeID='"+s1+"',attendanceDate='"+s2+"',present='"+s3+"' 
WHERE (counseleeID='"+s1+"' AND attendanceDate='"+s2+"') ";
                 pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                 pst.execute();


                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated");

                 comboBoxCounseleeID.setSelectedItem(null);
                 ((JTextComponent) dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).setText(""); //review   
                 comboBoxPresent.setSelectedItem("");


            } catch (Exception e2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e2);
            }

             finally {
                    try{
                      rs.close();
                          pst.close();
                        // conn.close();
                      }
                      catch(Exception e2) {
                                       }
                          } 
                Update_table();
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you click on button try to check you database whether that record is already stored by simply using `select`. If `ResultSet` contains records then use `update` query otherwise `insert` record into database.

Comment: I need help om how to write the IF ELSE statement that will determine when the system inserts or updates data. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment I have written a small code snippet that would help you. Consider you have table as this

```
-----------------------------------------
| id       | name        | salary       |
+----------+-------------+--------------+
| 1        | abc         | 2000         |
+----------+-------------+--------------+
| 2        | kbc         | 3000         |
+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

Table name: emp
Use the following code:

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Save");
btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)->{
      //assuming that you have already create the connection to database
      PreparedStatement ps = con.PreparedStatement("select * from emp where id=?");
      ps.setInt(1,yourInput);
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
      if(rs.hasNext()) // means record is already available (i.e. Update record)
      {
            //update your record here
      }
      else            // means no record available (i.e. insert a record)
      {
            //insert you record here
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was finally able to get it right.